# Route according to request method in Laravel Dingo?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, dingo-api

I want to route requests according to request methods (GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT)

how do I do this in dingo?

I have tried this, but it isn't working.

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
$api->get('users', 'UserController@index', ['only' => [ 'index']]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Routing works the exact same way as it does in Laravel/Lumen (depending on where you're using this pacakge).

Your code is partly correct. When you use `$api->get` you only need to provide the URI it responds to and the action that should be taken. The third parameter is not required.

So it should look like this:

```
$api->get('users', 'UserController@index');
```

Now when you browse `/api/users` it will look for the `UserController` and use the `index` method. It should be worth noting that you may need to include the full namespace to the controller, e.g., `App\Http\Controllers` for a fresh Laravel install.

You can utilize the other HTTP verbs as well, much like in Laravel/Lumen.

```
$api->post('users', 'UserController@create');
```

Finally, you can utilize resource controllers, which is what the third parameter is for in your example.

```
$api->resource('users', 'UserController', ['only' => ['index', 'create']]);
```

**Note:** All of these must be contained within an API version group, e.g., `$api->version('v1', function ($api) { });`